# How can I output the estimated values of the model coefficients?

Tags: r, curve-fitting

Sorry if this is a novice question, but I don't understand it. I am fitting a sigmoid curve to my data with `glm()`. This works, I can plot the output and I see a nice sigmoid curve.

However, how do I get R to return the final values it has fit? As I understand it, R fits the data to `logit(y) = b0 + b1x`, but when I do `> summary(glm.out)` I only get

```
Call:
glm(formula = e$V2 ~ e$V1, family = binomial(logit), data = e)

Deviance Residuals: 
       1         2         3         4         5         6         7  
-0.00001  -0.06612  -0.15118  -0.34237   0.20874   0.08724  -0.19557  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  -24.784     20.509  -1.208    0.227
e$V1           2.073      1.725   1.202    0.229

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 4.60338  on 6  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 0.23388  on 5  degrees of freedom
AIC: 5.8525

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 8
```

How do I get b0 and b1?

A sample dataset:

The Z column can be ignored.

```
X   Y   Z
0.0 0.0 6
6.5 0.0 3
8.8 0.333333333333  3
10.5    0.2 10
11.1    0.0 3
11.25   0.166666666667  6
12.0    0.2 5
12.75   0.5 6
13.4    0.333333333333  3
13.5    0.2 5
14.25   0.5 6
15.0    0.333333333333  6
15.7    0.666666666667  3
15.75   0.666666666667  6
16.5    0.833333333333  6
17.25   0.555555555556  9
18.0    1.0 3
```

Comment: Post a sample of your data, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the fitted values via the `fitted()` method, i.e. `fitted(glm.out)`. However, you want the estimated coefficients not the fitted values, and for that you want the `coef()` method, as in `coef(glm.out)`.

Comment: and `methods(class="glm")` for seeing other things you can do with the fitted model ...